# Nested Angular Directive behaving differently with `template` vs. `templateUrl`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a 'helper' directive that allows me to easily access child DOM elements within the parent directive. However, I'm running into an issue when I'm using this helper directive in conjunction with another directive. If I use a `template` in the directive, everything works fine. However, if i use a `templateUrl` i get an error saying the element the helper directive saves to scope is undefined.

A little hard to explain, but here's the plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NHKBGfro7Xe3dSalq5bt?p=preview

NOTE: that i've added a setTimeout that fires after 5 seconds, which allows the `templateUrl` directive to work, since it's now available on the scope of the parent directive.

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior.

> [angularjs $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)
>
> Post-linking function
> Executed after the child elements are linked.
>
> Note that child elements that contain templateUrl directives will not have been compiled and linked since they are waiting for their template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been suspended until that occurs.
>
> It is safe to do DOM transformation in the post-linking function on elements that are not waiting for their async templates to be resolved.

[Related Github Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8877#issuecomment-54129804)

Comment: whether you use pre or post this concept remain same. Spend some time in reading the links which I have mentioned.